# Why does this code refuse to check (12, 13)?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working on a Java challenge to evaluate all the digits in two different numbers and return true if any two digits are equal. The code works absolutely fine except when it tries to evaluate (12, 13), for some reason it doesn't even test the parameters it just instantly returns false.

I've ran the code through a visualiser to see each step and there doesn't seem to be any explanation for why it returns false. The message also outputs fine so there isn't an issue with the method call. Have I done something wrong that I'm not able to see?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(12, 23) + " should return true");
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(9, 99) + " should return false");
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(15, 55) + " should return true");
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(12, 43) + " should return false");
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(15, 76) + " should return false");
    System.out.println(hasSharedDigit(12, 13) + " should return true");
}

public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int first, int second) {
    if ((first >= 10 && first <= 99) && (second >= 10 && second <= 99)) {
        int firstDigits = 0;
        int secondDigits = 0;
        while (first != 0) {
            firstDigits = first % 10;
            first = first / 10;
            while (second != 0) {
                secondDigits = second % 10;
                second = second / 10;
                if (firstDigits == secondDigits) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: You keep reusing `second` between iterations of the outer loop, so this will only work in some cases depending on the order of the digits.

Comment: The check `if (firstDigits == secondDigits) {` will compare the least significant digits, i.e. 2 and 3. You are never check if first and second are the same.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks. I didn't notice that second would be at 0 before it checked the second number, I forgot to reset seconds after each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the part with

```
if (firstDigits == secondDigits) {
                return true;
            }
```

is under your

```
while (second != 0)
```

put the

```
if (firstDigits == secondDigits) {
                return true;
            }
```

after the while loop cause at the case 12,13 you get

```
second = 0
```

and then your first & second Digits won't get checked.

Answer (score 1):

//Try this it will work

```
public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int first, int second) {
    if ((first >= 10 && first <= 99) && (second >= 10 && second <= 99)) {
        int firstDigits = 0;
        int secondDigits = 0;
        while (first != 0) {
            firstDigits = first % 10;
            first = first / 10;

            while (second != 0) {
                secondDigits = second % 10;
                second = second / 10;
            }
            if (firstDigits == secondDigits) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

}